# Simple PHP to Ajax 'not logged in' error - how?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Currently I am using this to send success or failure to ajax:

```
$response = array( 'success' => true );
wp_send_json_success($response);
```

However, say the user is not logged in and I would like to end the php function right there, and send the error message that would prompt a login modal to popup. How would I do that?  Like:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in)) {
wp_send_json_error('not logged in');
die()
}
```

or I could use the more common json_encode($response);

```
if(!is_user_logged_in)) {
echo json_encode($response);
die()
}
```

but how would this handler even know an error occurred? If I put all my options for success and errors into an array, how do I die() the function while still returning the json response?  and how do I tell php which response to send?

Once it reached my ajax call, I am confident I can figure it out. Something like this is what I read:

```
var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Some examples would be of great help.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $response = array(
               'loggedIn' => false,
               'alertMsg' => 'not logged in :,-(',
    );
} else {
    $response = array(
               'loggedIn' => true,
               'success'  => true,
               'alertMsg' => 'test!',
    );

}
wp_send_json_success($response);
die();
```

The Ajax call is something like:

```
jQuery.get('pathToYourJsonFunctionURL', function(data) {
    if (data.loggedIn == true) {
        jQuery('#divForLoggedInStatus').text('You are logged in');
    } else {
        jQuery('#divForLoggedInStatus').text('You are NOT logged in');
    }

    window.alert(data.alertMsg);
});
```

When you return JSON data, you do not use `parseJSON` (the data is already (parsed) json). `data.loggedIn` is the same as in PHP returned `array('loggedIn' => value);`

Comment: Quick followup Dan - Say I want to use that alert message field to pass the total number of votes for a comment or post.  I tried passing it as a php variable with no luck.  Is this possible?

Comment: Everything is possible! Can you send me the code (PHP and JS) as pastebin or as a new question I can have a look then

Comment: Thank you Dan!  How can i contact you outside of stackoverflow?  Maybe you are for hire and affordable?  Here is the pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/8KZDEQnj

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_encode and make your own protocol like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['operation']) && $_POST['operation'] == 'is_user_logged_in'){
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $response->success = false;
        $response->msg = "not logged in";
    }else{
        $response->success = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

Then in your ajax:

```
$.post('AJAX-URL-HERE',{"operation":"is_user_logged_in"},function(response){
    if(response.success){
         //do whatever
    }else{
         var message = response.msg
         //pop up the login modal
    }
},'json').error(function(){alert('Call error')});
```

Comment: I tried this, using just alert(message); but it returns undefined for some reason.